# Elasticsearch REST search API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have problem with remote address of elasticsearch nad REST API (with getting search results)

I'm using ELK stack created by jHispter (logstash + Elasticsearch + Kibana). When I use REST search API (by cURL) with external server address I get fewer results than when I use localhost:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?q=Method:location"
{"took":993,"timed_out":false,"num_reduce_phases":13,"_shards": 
{"total":6370,"successful":6370,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits": 
{"total":8994099,"max_score":5.0447145,"hits":[..]}}
```

when executed from different server it returns smaller number of shards and hits:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://SERVER_URL/logstash-*/_search?q=Method:location"
{"took":10,"timed_out":false,"_shards": 
{"total":120,"successful":120,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits": 
{"total":43,"max_score":7.5393815,"hits":[..]}}
```

If I create ssh tunnel it works:

```
ssh -L 9201:SERVER_URL:9200 elk-stack
```

and now:

```
$ curl -X GET "localhost:9201/logstash-*/_search?q=Method:location"
{"took":640,"timed_out":false,"num_reduce_phases":13,"_shards": 
{"total":6370,"successful":6370,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits": 
{"total":8995082,"max_score":5.0447145,"hits":[..]}}
```

so there must be some problem with accessing data outside of localhost but I cant find in configuration how to change it (maybe some kind of default behaviour to prevent data leakage when accessing from remote?)

Comment: Are you certain that `SERVER_URL` points to the same cluster than the one listening on `localhost:9200` on your server?

Comment: Yes, its simple one node instalation running in docker containers. First request was done from server that runs all docker containers. The 'elk-stack' in ssh request is configured in.ssh/config and Hostname from it is the same as SERVER_URL

Comment: @Val thanks you for your comment, you where right - there was some strange configuration in /etc/hosts with the server url that pointed to test kibana instance

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

you should config your host

for this , In the config/elasticsearch.yml  file put this line:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```